# How to find the key of a higher level dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I had a dictionary structured as so:

```
wordDict = {word : {document ID : number of times that it appears in the document}}
```

This dictionary has thousands of words and documents.

I make a simple search like so:

```
for word in search:
        lookup(word) in wordDict
```

But I get an error "undefined name lookup"

I just want to find the word in wordDict I know it is in there?

Comment: use `wordDict.keys()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

What is `lookup` supposed to do? If you just want to know if the word is IN your outer dictionary, drop the function call.

```
for word in some_search:
    word in wordDict # True or False
```

Alternatively if you're trying to get the dictionary that's keyed by that word (the inner dictionary), then do:

```
for word in some_search:
    wordDict[word]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `search` is a list of strings, you could say

```
for word in search:
    value = wordDict.get(word)
```

If `word` exists as a key in the dictionary, `get` will return the inner dictionary and assign it to `value`.

If `word` does not exist, it will assign `None`.